# How to SELECT the group by result from an IIF statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

let's say I have this table

```
ID  Item    Number
1   Pork    10
2   Fish    15
3   Carrot  5
4   Tomato  5
```

I'd like to group by the Item and name this group as "Category", then select the sum of number for each category, something like this:

```
SELECT Sum(Number) AS Total,
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY IIF(Item IN ('Pork', 'Fish'), 'Meat', 'Vegetable')
```

But how can I get the category name as I assigned?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @MartinParkin, it is SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like

```
SELECT 
 (CASE WHEN ITEM IN ('Pork', 'Fish') THEN 'Meat' ELSE 'Vegetable' END) TYPE, SUM(NUMBER)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN ITEM IN ('Pork', 'Fish') THEN 'Meat' ELSE 'Vegetable' END)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was actually aware of the usage of an outer SELECT. But I was just wondering if I can only use one SELECT statement to accomplish this? For example, will the two SELECT statements affect the performance given a huge table?

Comment: @tete i have edited answer by one select, please check latest version.

Comment: That works! Thanks. But I do have question when understanding the query: since I already assign the value in the GROUP BY using CASE, I assume it should have an internal column/group name, what is that? I mean can I refer it directly instead of using CASE in SELECT again? On the other hand, why does the query "SELECT (CASE WHEN ITEM IN ('Pork', 'Fish') THEN 'Meat' ELSE 'Vegetable' END) TYPE" work but simply "SELECT ITEM" does not? I mean these two queries use both the same column "Item", don't they? And in fact if I assign different values in two CASE, it won't work. Why is that?

Comment: I mean if I use GROUP BY (CASE WHEN ITEM IN ('Pork', 'Fish') THEN 'Meat' ELSE 'Vegetable' END) but SELECT (CASE WHEN ITEM IN ('Pork', 'Fish') THEN 'Normal' ELSE 'Vegetarian' END) TYPE, it won't work

Comment: You can not use the column that you mention in group by statement. It can be achieved by 2 select query one of is outer which i did in first version of this answer.

Comment: Yeah, I just feel weird about the syntax: in other situations SELECT (CASE WHEN ITEM IN ('Pork', 'Fish') THEN 'Meat' ELSE 'Vegetable' END) TYPE and SELECT ITEM would refer to the same column but in this case they don't. But anyway, thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `WITH` statement:

```
WITH T1 AS 
(
SELECT IIF(Item IN ('Pork', 'Fish'), 'Meat', 'Vegetable') as Grp,
       T.*
FROM T
)

SELECT Grp,SUM(Number) as Total
FROM T1
GROUP BY Grp
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a63ba/3)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Just out of curiosity, does it affect the performance, if I use WITH, or if I use an outer SELECT out of the original one to group again?